# Redis scale with number of clients

Tags: parallel-processing, redis

I am testing Redis performance on my local machine and I want to know how well Redis can scale when number of parallel connections increases. My machine has 24 cores. 
At first, I tested with -c = 8, the benchmark command is `./redis-benchmark -c 1 -n 100000 -t set,get`. The result is around 70K requests/s. Then I run `./redis-benchmark -c 8 -n 100000 -t set,get`. The result is 200K requests/s. Finally I run `./redis-benchmark -c 10 -n 100000 -t set,get`. It's still around 200K requests/s. I expected the throughput to increase around 8 times when the number of parallel connections increase 8 times. Also, why -c = 8 and -c = 10 has no difference? Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is single-threaded. The maximum QPS it can achieve, is limited by the power of a single processor. 200K might be the maximum QPS it can achieve (based on your hardware environment).

If you want to achieve higher QPS, you need a more powerful CPU or more Redis instances.